# Android Studio Locgat Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-debug

I have an Android Studio project named "SMSschoolNotifications" and I have another project named "CoLunch". Besides these two I have many other projects, however, I am experiencing a strange issue when running "SMSschoolNotifications" that is related to "CoLunch".

When running "SMSschoolNotifications" the debugger shows 
[image]

The Logcat shows this
[image]

*Why is it showing a package name from another project when I'm running the SMSschoolNotifications project?*

Answer (score 0):

you can use Filter Dialog on Android Studio to let it display log data from your package only. 
click Alt+6 and then from right side click on down arrow then "Edit Filter Configuration" 
[image: Filter Configuration]